# insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "IN_USE_ADDRESSES"

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Totally new to GCP and trying to deploy first kubernetes cluster and getting below error.

(1) insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "IN_USE_ADDRESSES": request requires '9.0' and is short '1.0'. project has a quota of '8.0' with '8.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=test-255811

Have already request for quota increase but I want to know what does this "8.0" limit mean? how many IP addressed are available in "1.0"? from where I can reduce the size of my network. I am using "default" Network and default "/20" Node Subnet options.

Answer (score 7):

The easy way to check quota usage for the current project is to go to

GCP Navigation => IAM & admin => Quotas,

then sort data by Current Usage.

There are regional hard limits that you could have exceeded (`In-use IP addresses` in your case).

The numbers in the error message are just decimal values in the format the `gcloud` and API commonly use for quotas. You might try the following commands to see how the quota values are actually displayed:

```
$ gcloud compute project-info describe --project project-name
$ gcloud compute regions describe region-name
```

In your particular case 9 addresses were requested, and the deployment was short of 1 address because of the quota of 8 addresses.

Google Cloud documentation provides viable explanation of quotas:

[Resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas)

[Working with Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota)

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same error and thought it was because of a global IP I claimed. The limit involved can be found
Under:

GCP Navigation => IAM & admin => Quotas:

```
Compute Engine API
Static IP addresses global
```

Apparently when creating a new cluster, 9 free IPs are needed.

An option seems to be to ask for the limit to be increase the limit under quotas, which seems the only option because by default the number of nodes created by the gcloud container clusters create command is 3 and it seems there is 3 static address allocated for each node.

If you really don't need all those static addresses you can specify 2 nodes which should only allocate 6 static addresses via the --num-nodes switch eg.

gcloud container clusters create  --num-nodes=2

After creation there are not 8 IP's used so the global IP that was removed can be re-added.

Ref: [GKE: Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "IN_USE_ADDRESSES"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942642/gke-insufficient-regional-quota-to-satisfy-request-resource-in-use-addresses)

An easy way to get the whole cloud command is to click on the command line link in the lower left button. it shows the gloud console command.

You can easily change the --num-nodes option there.
I think the GUI was changed, it would be useful if Google aligns their defautl settings with their default UI options, so users do not get this message.

Reported at Google :
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156318821

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting this whilst running through one of the Google GCP tutorials, it's likely that you chose a compute zone that would create more pods than your quota allows by default.

For example, you may have done this:

```
$ gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west2
```

which would create 3 pods by default in west2-a, west2-b and west2-c.  9 in total for a quota of 8.

You could be more specific with the zone (by adding **-a** to the zone for example) which would create fewer pods, and therefore require fewer IPs:

```
gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west2-a
```

Comment: I was following the GCP tutorial and this is the right answer, thanks! This tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is caused by the external IPv4 addresses. 
https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/

How many nodes are you creating in your cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Under Cluster Basics -> Location Type select the check box "Specify default node locations".
Select only 1 or two zones here to result in 3 or 6 nodes to belaunched.
Default is 3 and that is causing 9 noted to be launched, and exceed 9 IP address quota for free tier.