# GKE: Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "IN_USE_ADDRESSES"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to create a GKE cluster using:

```
gcloud container clusters create mycluster --region europe-west1
```

but I'm having an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "IN_USE_ADDRESSES": request requires '9.0' and is short '1.0'. project has a quota of '8.0' with '8.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=myproject-xxxx.
```

It seems that there's a problem with the limit of the resource IN_USE_ADDRESSES. This is weird because the project is new therefore I don't have any resource except the cluster I want to crate.  I have a second project in which I deployed a postgres DB. Nothing more.

When I visit the quota page, it seems that I didn't exceed any limit.

[image]

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IN_USE_ADDRESSES` means both static and ephemeral IP addresses. To create your cluster requires a total of 9 (which includes all of your services in the region) but your quota only allows for 8 addresses total.

Solution: Request a quota increase. Follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) to understand how to request a quota link. A quota increase is requested in the Google Cloud Console. Tip: Increase both global and regional. This will cover load balancers in the future (and other services that use Global IP addresses).

Comment: Thanks, however, simple question. I have 10 services (2 APIs services, 8 backend services). Is it a good practice for all of them to have their own external IPs or no?

Comment: That depends on your design. Typically, with Kubernetes, you would use path based routing so that each service does not require its own public IP address. If you need more help on this topic, create a new question as there are many methods.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same problem, by default the number of nodes created by the `gcloud container clusters create` command is 3 and it seems there is 3 static address allocated for each node.

If you really don't need all those static addresses you can specify 2 nodes which should only allocate 6 static addresses via the `--num-nodes` switch eg.

`gcloud container clusters create <cluster-name> --num-nodes=2`

Comment: Thanks. It solved my problem but I notice that I get 6 nodes! Can you look at this please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62548469/6-nodes-created-by-kubernetes-on-gcp-when-num-nodes-was-set-to-2

Comment: Yes that is correct, 2 nodes * 3 static address = a total of 6 instances

Comment: do you know the *terraform* config for this? I've tried google_container_node_pool.node_count, but I'm now sure if using cluster_autoscalling should override this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Request a quota increase from the GCP support team. Or reduce the number of nodes you are creating, gcloud container clusters create --name --num-nodes (e.g 2) --zone (choose a zone)... alternatively you can set a zone to use, i.e, gcloud config set compute/zone (your chosen zone), this way you dont have to keep on updating the zone you want to create your infra in.

Answer (score -1):

you also need to choose a zone for the cluster, use gcloud container clusters create [insert cluster name here] --num-nodes 3 --zone us-central1-f(or any zone you want)...by using the region, if you specify 2 nodes, in every zone 2nodes will be provided thats why you are exceeding the quota...