# GCP Kubernetes created 6 nodes when num-nodes was set to 2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am following this tutorial to configure Kubernetes on GCP.
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app#clean-up

I run this command to create a cluster following the suggestion from here - [GKE: Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "IN_USE_ADDRESSES"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58942642/gke-insufficient-regional-quota-to-satisfy-request-resource-in-use-addresses)

```
gcloud container clusters create name-cluster --num-nodes=2
```

When I list the nodes using `gcloud compute instances list` I notice that I have got more than 2 nodes!! Why?

```
NAME                          LOCATION      MASTER_VERSION  MASTER_IP      MACHINE_TYPE   NODE_VERSION    NUM_NODES  STATUS
name-cluster  europe-west4  1.14.10-gke.36  34.91.182.235  n1-standard-1  1.14.10-gke.36  6 <-- why not 2         RUNNING

gcloud compute instances list
gke-name-cluster-default-pool-6eb04e1c-8v7v  europe-west4-a  n1-standard-1                           10.164.0.7   34.91.242.41    RUNNING
gke-name-cluster-default-pool-6eb04e1c-k2c7  europe-west4-a  n1-standard-1                           10.164.0.8   34.91.149.207   RUNNING
gke-name-cluster-default-pool-aa8d2ab0-9508  europe-west4-b  n1-standard-1                           10.164.0.11  34.91.209.197   RUNNING
gke-name-cluster-default-pool-aa8d2ab0-vpv2  europe-west4-b  n1-standard-1                           10.164.0.12  35.204.159.132  RUNNING
gke-name-cluster-default-pool-ae1131d2-9q50  europe-west4-c  n1-standard-1                           10.164.0.10  34.90.135.116   RUNNING
gke-name-cluster-default-pool-ae1131d2-l29c  europe-west4-c  n1-standard-1                           10.164.0.9   34.91.4.206     RUNNING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the `compute/zone` property like suggested in the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app#step_4_create_a_cluster) you followed?

Like:

```
gcloud config set compute/zone europe-west4-b
```

Check it with:

```
gcloud config get-value compute/zone
```

Or you can set it directly as an argument when creating the cluster:

```
gcloud container clusters create cluster-name --num-nodes=2 --zone=europe-west4-b
```

I see that `LOCATION` of your cluster is `europe-west4` which is a whole **region**, and not a **zone**. And since the region `europe-west4` has [3 zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) (`a`, `b`, `c`), it created 3 * 2 instances, as explained in [Gautam Savaliya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62549069/2791390)

Answer (score 2):

Argument `num-nodes` is the number of nodes in the pool in a zonal cluster. If you use multi-zonal or regional clusters, num-nodes is the number of nodes for each zone the node pools is in.

In your case, GKE cluster is deployed in `europe-west4` region and it created 2 nodes in each zone(europe-west4-a, europe-west4-b, europe-west4-c).

For more reference [resizing cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/resizing-a-cluster#resize)